# Date format in models

Tags: django-models

Hello how do i change the date format in models 
for Eg: i have 
date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

by default it yyyy-mm-dd format how do i change it to dd-mm-yyyy format

Answer (score 2):

A date is a date, and doesn't have a "format". A format applies when you represent the date as a string, or when you wish to interpret a string as a date.

Comment: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

then what is this all about

Comment: That's all about, as I said, "when you represent the date as a string, or when you wish to interpret a string as a date".

Answer (score 1):

You could play around with [DATE_INPUT_FORMATS](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-input-formats) and similar settings for your project.

You define the setting in the `settings.py` file for your project. For instance:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y', '%Y-%m-%d', '%m/%d/%Y', '%m/%d/%y', '%b %d %Y',
                      '%b %d, %Y', '%d %b %Y', '%d %b, %Y', '%B %d %Y',
                      '%B %d, %Y', '%d %B %Y', '%d %B, %Y')
```

Comment: You use it in your settings.py file (for example DATETIME_FORMAT = 'N j, Y, P'). You can find allowed options here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ttag-now

Answer (score 0):

You're better off worrying about the format on output, not how it is stored.  A `DateField` is stored as your database's native column of the same type.

If you really want this, you can set `DATE_FORMAT` in your `settings.py`, like so:

```
DATE_FORMAT='d-m-Y'
```

This makes a default display like this:

```
Feb 5, 2010
```

Look like this:

```
05-02-2010
```

Now of course there are other places where this will be overridden, such as the admin app and default form widgets, so it's not like this is a total solution to all your problems.  Just get used to using `datetime.datetime.strftime()` like so:

```
>>> # using one of my own apps as an example where 'created' is a DateTimeField
>>> r.created
datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 28, 10, 5, 19, 38963)
>>> print r.created # default output (this is a Python default)
2010-01-28 10:05:19.038963
>>> print datetime.datetime.strftime(r.created, "%m-%d-%Y") # forcing it to m-d-Y format
01-28-2010
```